# Warm-weather UL breathable packable waterproof jacket

Tags: hiking, jackets, waterproof-clothing

I guess I might be asking for too much but I'm trying to find a very breathable, light, packable waterproof jacket. I'd like to be able to hike in ~75F rain while remaining relatively comfortable for less than 9 oz. in weight. I want to be prepared for something like a 15 minute pour.

I've been researching jackets for a couple days and I think I'm further from making a decision than when I started. I have an amazing 17 oz., 4-season hard shell already so I don't want anything like that.

In my research I've found that reviews generally cover experiences in cooler weather, but that doesn't help me since I'll be doing a multi-day hike in warmer weather. The reviews also tend to conflict. Any input would be helpful.

As of mid-2018, some good choices with pit zips appear to include:

- Montbell Versalite
- Marmot Essence
- Patagonia Nano-Air
- Outdoor Research Helium II (no pit zips)

Plus a bunch more that I read about, in addition to all the ones I'm sure are out there and didn't see. Is there any gear that would check these requirements?

Comment: breathable clothings work thanks to the difference in absolute humidity and temperature between the inside and outside. In warm environments during or after rain the difference will be much smaller than in cold weather, so I wouldn't expect any membrane to work very well (looking for vents/pit zips is a good idea though). I'm looking for a formula for calculating Moisture vapor transmission rate or differential pressure based on the temperature/humidity diff. - will post if I find something useful

Comment: It seems like it would be possible to word this question in a way that gives it lasting value. Right now it seems like it won't be relevant in 2019.

Comment: But - here's another question with a price shopping close vote, but there's nothing about price in the question. It's one of those things that makes me want to go, "hmmmmm."

Comment: @DonBranson If you click the link in price shopping which is best is an example of not in scope.

Comment: @paparazzo - Interesting. Well, maybe dropping the word "price" would help. The description is well-done, though.

Comment: @DonBranson I didn't mention price because it'll be my final deciding factor. First, I'd just like to get a list of good jackets for the above use going. Once I have that, I'll go with the best bang for the buck. But including price would be useful. See edit.

Comment: The point of the price discussion is that if the question includes it, then it should be closed, according to the close option

Comment: @DonBranson So you just going to ignore the clarification link in the close option?

Comment: @paparazzo - No, I responded to you.

Comment: @DonBranson Don't follow your logic.  No problem.  Moving on.

Comment: @paparazzo - It's actually not complicated. The close reason includes the word "price," but the description really explains that it's not all about price, so we should drop that from the reason. I guess you'd like to me respond with a close vote instead? I could do that, but a more pensive response could help the OP to reformulate the question to have more lasting value.

Comment: @DonBranson You are fine.  Not my intent to argue with you.

Comment: trijamms, sorry for the argumentative discussion, and my part in it! I see you've been at SO for over a year, so you've probably seen the [help]. The price/shopping thing is confusing although we're definitely supposed to keep price out of it. Our [on topic page](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) offers some clarity. It says,  "**Recommendations for what item to purchase are off-topic**; questions about what features one should look for are on-topic." (Bold in original.) Maybe you could edit based on that.

Comment: @Sue The warning about shopping has been out for a while and OP has made no attempt to correct.

Comment: @Sue I removed the reference to price. I'm looking for recommendations for gear that fits a certain set of criteria so I'm not sure if my question is on-topic or not. It seems kind of in-between. Feel free to decide which and remove if necessary.

Comment: voting to close. This is a shopping list question, because you want suggestions for and advise about concrete products, and as such it becomes obselete very quickly and it's usage to other users is very limited. You could ask if there are any special membranes/fabrics/etc for high-temperature waterproofness and breathability, though.